# I am using a pure JavaScript calendar for displaying the dates. I want to implement a swipe functionality to load the previous and the next dates

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using a pure JavaScript function for displaying a calendar in a HTML5 page.
How can I implement a swipe functionality without using the hyperlinks.
A part of the code is:

```
cal += '<table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" width="700px" align="center" height="70px"><tr><td><a href="#" onclick="if (cala = dispCal('
                + yb
                + ','
                + mm
                + ')) {document.getElementById(\'cal\').innerHTML = cala; return false;}">previous year</a></td><td></table>';
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already started with?

Comment: yes. i was able to implement it succesfully by using the jquery datepicker.

the implementation is as follows:

$('#datepicker').live("swipeleft", function(){
  var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
  var month=date.getMonth();
  var a=new Date(); 
  if(month<11)
  {
  a.setMonth(month+1); 
  }
 
 else
  
  {
  a.setMonth(0); 
  }
   
  $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( "setDate",  a); 

});

Am using Jquery Datepicker

Comment: Can you add the code from your comment as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer if it fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote an answer in comments:

> I was able to implement it successfully by using the jQuery datepicker. The implementation is as follows:
>
> ```
> $('#datepicker').live("swipeleft", function(){ 
>    var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'); 
>    var month=date.getMonth(); 
>    var a=new Date(); 
>    if(month<11) { 
>      a.setMonth(month+1); 
>    } else { 
>      a.setMonth(0); 
>    } $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( "setDate", a); 
>  });
> ```